# LibreOffice calc countifs with date

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, countif

I got 3 columns. 1 column(D) text, 1 column(T) 0 or 1, 1 column date(A) 01.01.2010 till 31.12.2014 .

I want to count up until a specific date, for example 10.10.2011:

> =COUNTIFS($D$1:$D$1000;"Law";$T$1:$T$1000;"1";$A$1:$A$1000;?????)

This is where I fail.

Excel had something like that

> =COUNTIFS(B14:B17,">=1/1/2010",B14:B17,"<=12/31/2010")

But that doesn't work in LibreOffice. Anyone know a way?

Comment: What happens if you do `...; $A$1:$A$1000; "<=12/31/2010")`? How about `...; $A$1:$A$1000; "<="&DATE(2010,12,31))`?

Comment: The proper syntax for your Excel example would be `=COUNTIFS(B14:B17,">="&DATE(2010,1,1),B14:B17,"<="&DATE(2010,12,31))`. Not sure how it translates to LibreOffice.

Comment: The proper syntax for Excel is completely irrelevant here. I just put it there for the "<=12/31/2010", something like that I'm missing in LibreOffice. @G-Man, nope, does't work. :(

Comment: Do you have also Excel? If yes, try to create formula there, then open it in LibreOffice and save as it's format, hopefully it'll convert the formula.